# Is a question about portable air conditioning on topic?

Tags: discussion

The air cond on on 1991 Mazda MX5 is dead & can't be resurrected.

I wondered if there is anything I can plug into the cigarette lighter, to cool the small, 2 seater, car. I am thinking of a box that sits on the rear parcel shelf, rather then a fan for the dash.

Would such a question be on topic here?

Comment: Whaaat? Not resurrectable?  Surely you could fix it if you wanted to..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be asking for product recommendations, which generally aren't on topic. You're welcome to ask it on the chat though...

Saying that, AC on an MX5? It's a soft top, open the roof! ;-)

Comment: Or, I might ask on our [LifeHack](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) site. My softop Florida MX5 is mow in Merrie Englande, with hardtop.  There are occssional warm days, and I was thinking of something other than lowering the windows :-)